# Is there a way to programatically build a CSS selector chain in stylus?

Tags: stylus

I am trying to figure out, how to build a CSS Selector in a "for in" loop.

Something along the lines:

```
ul
    for row in 1 .. 4
        li*{row}                 <=== thats the tricky part 
            padding: 10px * row
```

it should yield as:

```
ul li{ padding: 10px }
ul li li{ padding: 20px }
ul li li li{ padding: 30px }
ul li li li li{ padding: 40px }
```

Is that possible??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
ul
  el = ''
  for row in 1..4
    el += ' li'
    {el}
      padding row * 10px
```

You might want to create a mixin for this, I leave that as an exercise for you!

**Edit:** Output:

```
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li li {
  padding: 20px;
}
ul li li li {
  padding: 30px;
}
ul li li li li {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of a mixin/function to do this for you:

```
build_selector(selector, count)
  $out = selector

  for i in 1..count
    {$out}
        padding i * 10px
    $out += ' ' + selector


ul
    {build_selector(li, 4)}
```

Produces:

```
ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li li {
    padding: 20px;
}
```